# How can I run Rosetta Stone (on Wine) from the menu in Crunchbang?

Tags: wine, crunchbang

I added this entry to menu.xml:

```
<item label="Rosetta">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>
       wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Rosetta\ Stone/Rosetta\ Stone\ Version\ 3/RosettaStoneVersion3.exe
    <command>
</action>
</item>
```

But when I click this, Rosetta opens with error 2123.  This error, I think, is associated with bad shortcuts.  I'm not sure.

However, when I go to the folder and click on the exe file, it runs correctly.

I tried prepending the command with 'sudo'.  Didn't help.

The command must be incorrect but I don't know why.

What am I doing wrong?

**Just to be clear:**
When I click the Rosetta Stone icon, the program runs.
When I navigate to the folder in terminal and use "wine RosettaStoneVersion3.exe", it also runs.
But when I run "wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Rosetta\ Stone/Rosetta\ Stone\ Version\ 3/RosettaStoneVersion3.exe", it opens with "error 2123".

I can't figure out why this would be.

Comment: [According to this](http://success.rosettastone.com/articles/en_US/Text/How-can-I-resolve-error-2123/?q=2123&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1) it's a permission conflict. How did you install the app?

Comment: Try doing `cd` to directory with .exe before running it with wine

Comment: @gelraen I added some details to my question.  If I cd there, it runs fine.  But when I use a path, I get error 2123.  I can't understand this.

Comment: Well, it seems pretty obvious to me that this crap just unable start from anywhere but it's own directory. So just use something like `cd ... && wine crap.exe` as a command. Or `sh -c 'cd ... && exec wine crap.exe'` if that doesn't work.

Comment: well, it's pretty usual for windows software to run only from some specific directory. Installer-created shortcuts usually have working directory specified, so that's not a problem in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gelraen Your answer gave me what I needed. The solution turned out to be sh -c 'cd ... && exec wine Rosetta.exe' Pretty frustrating bug. Thanks for you help! :) And I agree. Rosetta sucks. I'm setting this up for a friend.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, it appears to be the path you are giving `wine` (disclaimer: I have no clue at all about the way that Openbox parses `menu.xml`).

You currently have:

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Rosetta\ Stone/Rosetta\ Stone\ Version\    3/RosettaStoneVersion3.exe
```

Note the three spaces between "Version" and "3". If there are truly three spaces, you want:

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Rosetta\ Stone/Rosetta\ Stone\ Version\ \ \ 3/RosettaStoneVersion3.exe
```

If there is only one space, remove the trailing spaces.

Comment: I just typed it incorrectly in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this was toiling my brain for some time. I followed [this](http://www.geekthis.net/blog/120/add-wine-programs-to-menu-in-linux) guide initially. Rosetta Stone wouldn't launch. I use Lubuntu 14.10 x64. Here was my solution.

**Part 1:**

navigate to `~/.local/share/applications`

right click created file and click `Properties -> Desktop Entry`

**Part 2:**

for the command put:

```
sh -c 'cd "~/.wine/drive_c/<directory with Rosetta Stone>" && exec wine "YourRosetta.exe"'
```

Seems there was a problem with the format before.