# Launch Picasa under CrunchBang Waldorf

Tags: command-line, wine, crunchbang

I succesfully installed Picasa 3.9 under Crunchbang following this [webupd8-tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-picasa-39-in-linux-and-fix.html). I also installed `libwine-cms:i386`. Everything works well and Picasa launches after installation.

The problem: once I close it, I cannot get it to relaunch. I tried the following and neiither works:

- `picasa`
- `Picasa`
- `Picasa39`
- `wine picasa`
- `wine Picasa39`

On the wine-commands I get `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\picasa.exe"`, so I tried copying the .exe from "Program Files" to 'system32' but that also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this  [Rosetta-Stone question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62917/how-can-i-run-rosetta-stone-on-wine-from-the-menu-in-crunchbang) gave me the clue:

`cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Google/Picasa3`

`wine Picasa3.exe`